# Saving TimeSpan with value of 00:00:00 to database - Seen as NULL

Tags: vb.net, t-sql

I'm trying to save a TimeSpan variable from VB into a SQL database, into a non-null column.

It works fine for other values, but when I try to save 00:00:00 I am told that I cannot save NULL into a non-null column...

Is there a way to get it to actually save this rather than think that it's NULL?

Cheers

Note: This code is a method in a class, which has a property:

```
Private mCommand As New SqlCommand

Dim Param As New SqlParameter
Param.ParameterName = "@" + ParameterName
Param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar
If Value Is Nothing Then
   Param.Value = DBNull.Value
Else
   Param.Value = Value
End If
Param.Size = Size
Param.Direction = Direction

mCommand.Parameters.Add(Param)
```

Comment: Can you please post the query/code you are using?

Comment: Also, can you please describe the type of your database column (i.e. datetime, varchar, etc)

Comment: The column type is Time(0), I will now update the OP with the code

Comment: I just put the code in the OP.
Note that this part of the code worked (where adding the parameter) it was when executing the Stored Procedure that the error occured

Comment: Where is the query you use to `Save` the value into the database?

Comment: Oh, the actual SQL query? Its very complicated, but basically where the parameters are declared, i have: `@Time time(0),`
then just `insert into table(time) values(@Time)`, but with other columns as well obviously...

Comment: @NickDuffell execute it in debug mode and make a breakpoint in the `If Value Is Nothing Then` and check it if it's really nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's impossible to differentiate between if 00:00:00 is actually the value, or if it should be seen as Nothing.

I have therefore removed the check for Nothing in the code i posted above, and left it as just

```
Dim Param As New SqlParameter
Param.ParameterName = "@" + ParameterName
Param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar
Param.Value = Value
Param.Size = Size
Param.Direction = Direction

mCommand.Parameters.Add(Param)
```